# Testing contrasts in statistics: Is this provably a hard problem, or not?

Tags: st.statistics, linear-regression, np

[Scheffé's method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scheff%C3%A9%27s_method) for identifying statistically significant contrasts is widely known.  A **contrast** among the means $\mu_i$, $i=1,\ldots,r$ of $r$ populations is a linear combination $\sum_{i=1}^r c_i \mu_i$ in which $\sum_{i=1}^r c_i=0$, and a scalar multiple of a contrast is essentially the same contrast, so one could say the set of contrasts is a projective space.  Scheffé's method tests a null hypothesis that says *all* contrasts among these $r$ populations is $0$, and given a significance level $\alpha$, rejects the null hypothesis with probability $\alpha$ given that the null hypothesis is true.  And if the null hypothesis is rejected, Scheffé points out that his test tells us *which* contrasts differ significantly from $0$ (I'm not sure the Wikipedia article I linked to points that out).

I would like to know if one can do something similar in a different sort of situation.  Consider a simple linear regression model $Y_i = \alpha + \beta x_i + \varepsilon_i$, where $\varepsilon_i\sim\operatorname{i.i.d.}N(0,\sigma^2)$, $i=1,\ldots,n$.

The null hypothesis I want to consider concerns a different sort of contrast.  It says there is no subset $A\subseteq\lbrace 1,\ldots,n\rbrace$ such that $E(Y_i) = \alpha_1 + \beta x_i$ for $i\in A$ and $E(Y_i) = \alpha_2 + \beta x_i$ for $i\not\in A$, where $\alpha_1\ne\alpha_2$.  If the subset $A$ is specified in advance, then an ordinary two-sample $t$-test does it, but we want something that considers all subsets and holds down the probability of rejecting a true null hypothesis.

One could figure this out if efficiency were not a concern: find a test that goes through all $2^{n-1}-1$ possibilities.  Even then it's problematic; two contrasts would not be independent.  I asked an expert on outlier detection about this and he just said it's a combinatorial nightmare.  Then I asked if one could *prove* that there's no efficient way to do it, perhaps by reducing an NP-hard problem to it.  He just said he stays away from NP-hard problems.

So: Can one prove either that this problem is "hard" or that it's not?

Comment: Maybe about a year ago at a statistics seminar at the University of Minnesota, the speaker mentioned that a certain problem was NP-hard.  For reasons not related to that comment, I thought his topic might bear upon someething I'd wondered about.  The more routine but rather laborious exercises in applied statistics courses at a master's degree level include multiple linear regression problems in which one must do "subsetting", i.e. deciding which predictors to discard for lack of evidence that they matter.  The problem was how to adjust the sizes of confidence.......

Comment: ....intervals to take into account the uncertainties in subsetting.  I never heard that question addressed in a course. So I asked the speaker at that seminar about that.  His answer was startling: that is a _harder_ problem than the ones he had spoken on.

Comment: +1. Very nice problem.

Comment: +1.  Do you want some kind of requirement on the power of the test? The facetious test of randomly rejecting a certain fraction irrespective of the data is definitely polynomial time and trivially satisfies the control of false rejections. I don't think my question is just a nit-pick either, because it seems plausible to me that the hardness of the problem could be directly related to what other desiderata you add.

Comment: @RHahn, I was just about to write an almost identical (in content) comment. I'm glad I clicked to refresh the page before I did.

Comment: Just a small point of clarification: As I read it, $(1,2,3)$ qualifies under your null hypothesis, but $(1,2,2)$  and $(1,1,1)$ do not. Is that what you intended? (It doesn't seem to match some of the other allusions made in the question.)

Comment: @R Hahn : Well, I'd like it to conform to common sense and practicality.  The "facetious" test isn't so facetious if one views it as an admonition to be practical.

Comment: @cardinal : The hour is late.  I'll look at your example tomorrow..........

Comment: I say 'facetious' because when people mention 'random reject' tests it is often to attack hypothesis testing generically. The problem you describe is practically relevant; in clinical trials one will often find that a drug doesn't work on average, but appears to work on, say, white males with brown eyes. If you allow such subgrouping, you must account for multiple-testing issues you induce. Like your, my experience is that people working on this problem acknowledge that it is a 'combinatorial nightmare' but I have yet to see a formal articulation of computational hurdles involved.

Comment: @cardinal : I don't understand what you're saying?  Are the members of you triples supposed to be the coefficients $\alpha_1,\alpha_2,\beta$?

Comment: Why is the null hypothesis specified with respect to the sample? Shouldn't the null hypothesis be specified with respect to a hypothetical distribution the sample is drawn from?

Comment: @ArthurB : A null hypothesis is always a statement about the population from which the sample was taken, not a statement about the sample, and so it is in the present case.

Comment: "The null hypothesis I want to consider [...] says there is no subset A⊆{1,…,n} such that..." isn't $n$ the size of your sample? This sounds like a statement about your sample.

Your null hypothesis is that the underlying population is drawn from a linear model with a single intercept. I think what you're looking for a function of the data that grows with the differences in empirical intercepts over subsets of your sample, and for which you can calculate a statistic assuming the null hypothesis.

Comment: I don't mean to be a smartass about this, but hypothesis testing sweeps under the rug the task of coming up with an alternate model to fit the data. This comes at the cost of a certain vagueness.

Comment: OK, I should have phrased it differently.  The null hypothesis is that the model $\mathbb E(Y)=\alpha+\beta x$ is correct; the alternative hypothesis is that there are two subsets of the population for one of which $\mathbb E(Y)=\alpha_1+\beta x$ is right and for the other of which $\mathbb E(Y)=\alpha_2+\beta x$ is right.

Comment: Just wonder if there is any progress since this post is posted so long ago. Thx.

Comment: @Henry.L : None. (After seeing your comment, I remembered that there was a particular problem that inspired this question, but it took me a few minutes to remember what it was. It was the celebrated dataset concerning chocolate consumption and Nobel prizes that was getting publicized shortly before I posted this. The author of that paper ought to have taken logarithms of both of the two variables he plotted against each other. Then you get something that looks roughly bivariate normal. Without that, his claimed p-value is bogus. Here's one thing that (if I'm not mistaken) is$\,\ldots\qquad$

Comment: $\ldots\,$known to be NP-hard: taking into account the uncertainty in transformations of the sort that includes taking logarithms, when one calculates p-values. $\qquad$

Comment: ok, Maybe I was mistaken in that. What I was vaguely remembering is this: Suppose you have multiple predictor variables and you're regressing one variable on all of them. Based on statistical tests you're deciding which predictor variables to include and which to exclude. Then in finding p-values and confidence regions, how do you take into account the uncertainty in the decisions about which variables to include? That's NP-hard.

Comment: So what you really want to ask is a variable selection problem along with multiple comparison. That is generally NP hard, however, in statistics people usually admit *conditionality principle* which allows a statisticians to draw multiple comparison conclusions based only on those predictors he has chosen to include earlier. And by Birnbaum's Theorem, admitting conditionality and formal likelihood principle at the same time is equivalent to Bayesian analysis. In Bayesian analysis, people do not have confident intervals, so I guess that a deadlock....

Comment: Bu t these comments help clarifying the OP, will be interesting if you add you motivation in OP :)

Comment: @Henry.L : No -- I was not trying to ask about variable selection here.

Comment: @Henry.L : Also, I wasn't saying variable selection is hard; I was saying adjusting the confidence bounds for the uncertainty resulting from variable selection is hard.

Comment: Adjust the confidence region according to possible outcomes of variable-selection is NP right?

Comment: @Henry.L : Yes. But I've only seen that asserted; I don't know how to prove it.

Comment: Where did you see that though? I have never seen such a claim.

Comment: A seminar speaker said it. I don't remember who it was, but maybe I can find out. During his talk he asserted that a certain problem is NP-hard. I don't remember specifically what it was, but it reminded me of the one I mention above in comments, so I asked about the latter, and he said that is also NP-hard.